# Unit puma_app_production.service has a bad unit file setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, capistrano, puma, rbenv

When I start manually puma on the server - everything works as expected. But when I try to do it within Capistrano - I receive this error.
`Failed to restart puma_app_production.service: Unit puma_app_production.service has a bad unit file setting`

to start puma I use also **rbenv**

these are my files
`puma_app_production.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server for app (production)
After=network.target


[Service]
Type=simple
User=rails_api
WorkingDirectory=/home/rails_api/apps/app/current
# Support older bundler versions where file descriptors weren't kept
# See https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/3254
ExecStart=RBENV_ROOT=/home/rails_api/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=3.0.2 /home/rails_api/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec --keep-file-descriptors puma -C /home/rails_api/apps/app/shared/puma.rb
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR1 $MAINPID
StandardOutput=append:/home/rails_api/apps/app/current/log/puma.access.log
StandardError=append:/home/rails_api/apps/app/current/log/puma.error.log




Restart=always
RestartSec=1

SyslogIdentifier=puma

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I was trying to deal with this problem so I also added this line to `deploy.rb` file:
`append :rbenv_map_bins, 'puma', 'pumactl'`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but I'm also fighting this at the moment.

The underlying problem is the inclusion of environment variables in `ExecStart`.

So extract `RBENV_ROOT` and `RBENV_VERSION` from ExecStart and include it into two separate `Environment` variables.

```
ExecStart=/home/rails_api/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec --keep-file-descriptors puma -C /home/rails_api/apps/app/shared/puma.rb
Environment=RBENV_ROOT=/home/rails_api/.rbenv
Environment=RBENV_VERSION=3.0.2
```

Comment: you are right. I did the same thing and answered there https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma/issues/335